# How to resrtrict resolution in Android Manifest

Tags: android-manifest, screen-resolution

Can anyone simply explain how restrict small resolution for my app. For example, I want that my app will be appropriate for QVGA , WVGA and devices with more resolutions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You maybe mean that you don't want to support QVGA displays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your manifest file:

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="false"
    android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true"
    />
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: But WQVGA (240 320) and FWQVGA(240 432) have normal screens too.
How can I restrict low density(so I need all except low density)?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I need support API 7 and higher.
Any ideas?

Comment: @drifter, You should consider creating some additional questions

Answer (score 0):

Please read this documentation it will help you .
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html